# android app wont launch in my device

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, sony-xperia

I am having a Sony Xperia SP and i want to test the app against the device. Everything is perfect, got the adb installed and eclipse shows the device in the device chooser. but it shows a question mark symbol in the target field and i cant figure out what it is!

still, if i kick start the app on the device it hangs and the error log has some entries that i cant understand.. 
I am stuck with this for few hours now and its on my nerves already. 
your help will be great deed, thanks :)

these are the last few entries in the log cat

```
12-16 20:31:31.210: I/ethernet(2166): Loading ethernet jni class
12-16 20:31:31.250: D/AndroidRuntime(2166): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-16 20:31:34.340: D/AndroidRuntime(2181): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
12-16 20:31:34.340: D/AndroidRuntime(2181): CheckJNI is OFF
12-16 20:31:34.480: I/ethernet(2181): Loading ethernet jni class
12-16 20:31:34.530: D/AndroidRuntime(2181): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-16 20:31:37.610: D/AndroidRuntime(2194): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
12-16 20:31:37.610: D/AndroidRuntime(2194): CheckJNI is OFF
12-16 20:31:37.760: I/ethernet(2194): Loading ethernet jni class
12-16 20:31:37.800: D/AndroidRuntime(2194): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
```

Stuck at this point!

Comment: Post the logcat with the entries that you can't understand and maybe someone can. Also, make sure that you have selected "Allow third party apps" in your settings.

Comment: i cant post the logcat cos i dont have enough reputations, i am new to this site! but the last entry says "calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am" and its stuck there! and yeah i have checked "unknown sources" already! thanks @codeMagic

Comment: You can post logcat regardless of rep. Just edit your post and copy/paste the error log.

Comment: does the app start and crash, or just hangs on a black screen ?

Comment: @user2427819the app is not installed in the phone!

Comment: may be the device does'nt has the minimum requirements for the app :/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have a problem uploading the app to the device and/or connecting the android debugger:

**Check if you can even connect to the device**

You may be missing the Google USB driver, or perhaps a driver specific to your device used for USB connectivity to your PC:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

**Debugging on a physical device**

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: oh i did! the device is connected and i could see the entry in command promt when i execute the command adb devices!